# Google Apps Script - Creating Calendar Events

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

When creating a Calendar event is it possible for me to set the CREATED BY field, that appears once the event is created, based on the contents of a cell (e-mail addresses will be entered manually as it is a public form, the cell will be "D2")

Here's what I currently have:

```
function CreateEvent() {
var vSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var vS = vSS.getActiveSheet();  
var vStartDate = vS.getRange("B2").getValue();
var vEndDate = vS.getRange("C2").getValue();  
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(
 'blahblah.com_79u2vjeeepkpra94hp12nbscc0@group.calendar.google.com');
var event =  calendar.createEvent('Apollo 11 Landing',
 new Date(vStartDate),
 new Date(vEndDate));
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CREATED BY` field will always show the name (or email) of the person who created the event... are you really wanting to cheat on this and show someone else's name ?

Comment: This script is running behind a form which is public so anyone can fill it in, this means it doesn't capture their e-mail address when they complete it. I'm therefore asking each person to manually enter in their e-mail address in the hope that I can then set the CREATED BY field depending on their response.

Comment: this won't be possible. Why not mentioning their email in the title or description ? [created by : john.smith@mail.com]

Comment: Guess I will have to do it that way. Thanks Serge, you the man.